# How to run code whenever a value reaches a multiple of 50 in lua

Tags: lua

Pretty simple, dont really have any code to give but just as an example:

```lua
local n = 0
local clock = os.clock

function sleep(n)
    local t0 = clock()
    while clock() - t0 <= n do end
end

while True do
    sleep(1)
    n = n + 1
    (code to run when 'n' is a multiple of 50)
        print("n is a multiple of 50")
end
```

Pretty simple, Any help appreciated!

Comment: `if n%50==0 then`

Comment: Please could you explan a bit, more e.g. on where to use it? I'm pretty new to lua.

Answer (score 0):

not to wait for a long time, I took a small values:

```
local function sleep (a) 
    local sec = tonumber(os.clock() + a)
    while os.clock() < sec do 
    end 
end

local n = 0   
while true do  -- true~=True
    sleep(1)
    n = n + 1
     print(n)
    if n%5==0 then 
        print(n," - n is a multiple of 5")
    end
    
    if n>=10 then break end
end
```

and more: you need to wait for the result, when the script finishes working, such a feature of the Lua interpreter.